# ASP.NET MVC when i'm on identity pages (profile detail or pass reset) cant go back on home or other

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i'm logged in, and when i go to profile detail page, i can't move to other pages eg. Home or my own created pages. When i click on a tag with href to home page (in code normaly like  asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index") page only refresh and im still on same page (when i was on detail page, i'm after click on home page button i still there).

I don't know where is problem. Pages and controllers exists.

```
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
```

Example home button.

Here is website link. You can try register, i'm new in this so i don't know now what is wrong.

https://creattive.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Same on https://creattive.azurewebsites.net/Identity/Account/Login you cant move to other pages from there. :(

Comment: In code inspector, there is no URLs, why?

Comment: Can you include the code for the Login link?

Comment: Problem was in app.UseMvc() pleaced in startup.cs. Scaffolding identity after generate print me text doc where was "The generated UI requires MVC. To add MVC to your app:
1. Call services.AddMvc() from your ConfigureServices method
2. Call app.UseMvc() from your Configure method (after authentication)". so it was mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly believe that you have to do some research on Microsoft's documentation.
In my opinion, you will find the following article useful: [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller)

And try to understand out how MVC actually works.

If I had to guess, I believe that you haven't implemented the appropriate action methods in your corresponding controller, in order to handle the incoming URLs

Besides that take a look at these tutorials too: [ASP.NET MVC Tutorials](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/asp.net-mvc-tutorials)

Hope it helps.

Comment: When i write im new in this doesnt mean, that i dont search before i wrote here. I have created controllers, created role managers, created many to many one to one realtions and i only dont know what to looking for cause _ViewImports have @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers and still nothing. Thank you for replay.

Comment: In that case you implemented the necessary action methods which will handle the appropriate incoming url's

Comment: Yes, you're right. I use scaffolding to generate identity and in text doc after generating was : "The generated UI requires MVC. To add MVC to your app:
1. Call services.AddMvc() from your ConfigureServices method
2. Call app.UseMvc() from your Configure method (after authentication)" app.UseMvc()  destroy urls on this pages. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that I have helped.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you've got everything in the right place. Please check the following:

- `Startup.cs` - `Configure()`

  ```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
      pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });
  ```
- `_Layout.cshtml`

  ```
  <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Index</a>
  <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
  ```
- `Solution/Areas/Identity/Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml` & `Solution/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml`

  ```
  @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
  ```

Comment: Thank you for replay. Yes it was. Problem was in app.UseMvc() pleaced in startup.cs. Scaffolding identity after generate print me text doc where was "The generated UI requires MVC. To add MVC to your app: 1. Call services.AddMvc() from your ConfigureServices method 2. Call app.UseMvc() from your Configure method (after authentication)". so it was mistake.